# How to emit an event with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

i'm trying to create a simple class to emit an event in certain moment.
I get this javascript error : this.emit is not a function

This is the code:

```
var class_test = function(){};
class_test.prototype = {
   some_property: null,

    doSomething: function(msg) {
            this.some_property = msg;
            this.emit("somethingHappened");
        }
};


var test = new class_test();
test.doSomething('Example');

test.addEventListener('somethingHappened',function(){
    alert("Event");
},false);
```

Any suggestion?,Thanks!

Comment: That code is not using jQuery at all.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the class is wrong?

Comment: @hanskait: Do you know what jQuery is? And `emit()` comes from NodeJS. Is that what you're using?

Comment: @hanskait, well, it does not have the `emit()` method you're trying to call. If you wish to emit events with jQuery, I would suggest you use the library (`on()` instead of `addEventListener()` for instance) and refer to [the trigger() method](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with jQuery ,since you requested it :

```
var class_test = function(){
   this.dispatcher = $({});
};
class_test.prototype = {
   some_property: null,

    doSomething: function(msg) {
            this.some_property = msg;
            this.dispatcher.trigger("somethingHappened");
        }
};


var test = new class_test();


test.dispatcher.on('somethingHappened',function(){
    alert("Event");
});

test.doSomething('Example');
```